# Using new query as an alias

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have 2 tables:

Table with counters names(t1):

```
Counter_ID    Counter_Name 
         1          Apples
         2            Nuts
        ...
```

And table with counters values(t2):

```
Time   Counter_ID_1  Counter_ID_2
12:00            24            43
13:00            64            73  
     ...
```

Using SQL I'm trying to name my resulting columns from t2 as they are named in t1 to look like this:

```
Time         Apples          Nuts
12:00            24            43
13:00            64            73  
     ...
```

Here is my query (doesn't work):

```
select
 t2.Time as 'Time',
 t2.Counter_ID_1 as (select Counter_Name from t1 where Counter_ID=1),
 t2.Counter_ID_2 as (select Counter_Name from t1 where Counter_ID=2)
from t2
```

Any ideas?

**UPD:**
I know, DB design isn't very good, but it's not my DB, I'm just a RO-user :)

**UPD2:**
Thank you all! I understood, that in my case it's easier not to auto it, but to do query one time as I need it and edit aliases manually if table with names (t1) will be changed.

Comment: While this would be possible using dynamic SQL, I strongly suggest you to rethink your table design. There's **no** real link between your `names` table and `values` table other than concatenating the ID's from `names`.

Comment: Problem is it's not my table, it's big corporative system, I have no opportuninties to affect any design issues of this DB :)

Comment: If you have another row in t1 say `3 Orange` Where do you get the data from t2 to have a column as `Orange` in the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want dynamic aliases. SQL Server doesnt do that.
What you can do, other that redesigning your tables is

```
select
 Time as 'Time',
 Counter_Name as 'Apples'
 Counter_ID_2 'Nuts'
from t2
```

but of course, that will only work if you have pre-defined which columns you will be selecting.

Answer (score 1):

Return both the names and IDs in the resultset and defer to the calling application e.g.

```
SELECT
 t2.Time AS 'Time',
 t2.Counter_ID_1, s1.Counter_Name AS Counter_Name_1,
 t2.Counter_ID_2, s2.Counter_Name AS Counter_Name_2
FROM t2
     JOIN t1 AS s1 ON s1.Counter_ID = t2.Counter_ID_1
     JOIN t1 AS s2 ON s2.Counter_ID = t2.Counter_ID_2;
```

Comment: That is correct, but you have to use LEFT OUTER JOIN. You can miss full row when in original query you just get NULL.

Comment: @AndreyGurinov: "have to use LEFT OUTER JOIN" - I disagree: there are no nulls in the sample data and personally I don't do nulls ;)

Comment: I did tons of query remasterings where I moved scalar-like subqueries to the JOINs and my rule is always mind I've mentioned. Sure, for the sample data it works OK, but real life is a little bit complex :) Up from me!

Comment: @AndreyGurinov: I've yet to encounter a null in the **real** world: tell me, is it true they have a skyblue pink hue to them? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your design might be flawed. You can't mix static data like columns/column names with dynamics data.

But if you really want to go that way I think you might have to make 2 queries from the application. One to get the column names and then use that to build your actual query dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, following would create an executable dynamic statement that uses `t1` as input for the columnnames for `t2`

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQLStatement = 
          ISNULL(@SQLStatement, '') 
          + ', Counter_ID_' 
          + CAST(Counter_ID AS VARCHAR(32)) 
          + ' AS ' + Counter_Name                               
FROM    t1

SELECT  @SQLStatement = 'SELECT TIME ' + @SQLStatement + ' FROM t2'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQLStatement
```

**Broken down**

Declare a variable to hold the executable statement

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Concatenate all possible aliases into the executable statement, using `t1` as input. The result of this step will be in the form of `, Counter_ID_1 AS Apples, Counter_ID_2 AS Nuts`

```
SELECT  @SQLStatement = 
          ISNULL(@SQLStatement, '') 
          + ', Counter_ID_' 
          + CAST(Counter_ID AS VARCHAR(32)) 
          + ' AS ' + Counter_Name                               
FROM    t1
```

Add the `SELECT` and `FROM`clause

```
SELECT  @SQLStatement = 'SELECT TIME ' + @SQLStatement + ' FROM t2'
```

Execute the statement

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQLStatement
```